# Несколько функций get_posts на странице

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет!

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. 
На одной странице сайта на Wordpress нужно вывести несколько списков следующего формата:

**Название первой рубрики**

- Название материала из первой рубрики
- Название материала из первой рубрики

**Название второй рубрики**

- Название материала из второй рубрики
- Название материала из второй рубрики

**Название третьей рубрики**

- Название материала из третьей рубрики
- Название материала из третьей рубрики

Задачу решаю при  помощи функции get_posts() таким образом:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 1000, 'category' => 40));?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post) { the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php get_the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php get_the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Но при этом второй, третий и далее списки не отображаются. Происходит только вывод материалов из первой рубрики.

В чем я не прав и что неправильно делаю?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменил в цикле foreach the_post(); на setup_postdata($post); и проблема решилась. 
Но ваши ответы все равно интересны, т.к. чую, что сделано очень и очень грубо.